# mpi4py will not run on Yosemite

Tags: python, osx-yosemite, anaconda, mpi4py

I'm trying to learn how to use MPI with python.

When I try using mpi4py installed with Python 2.7.8 :: Anaconda 2.1.0, to run the helloworld script [here](http://materials.jeremybejarano.com/MPIwithPython/introMPI.html), I get the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sorry!  You were supposed to get help about:
    opal_init:startup:internal-failure
But I couldn't open the help file:
    /opt/anaconda1anaconda2anaconda3/share/openmpi/help-opal-runtime.txt: No such file or directory.  Sorry!
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[usrname] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file runtime/orte_init.c at line 79
[usrname] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file orterun.c at line 694
```

I uninstalled the conda-packaged mpi4py and tried installing using pip.  Installation failed with the following error message:

```
error: Cannot find 'mpi.h' header. Check your configuration!!!
```

After searching around, I tried the manual install shown [here](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/appendix.html#macosx-universal-sdk), but no dice.

Please help!

### SOLVED:

Anaconda hasn't yet packaged mpi4py to work with Yosemite. You can install with the conda commands [here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mpi4py/ULMq-bC1oQA)

Comment: Looks like there was an issue with how the package was built.

Comment: I had this issue also. It cost me a couple hours until I found this post. I ran the command "conda install --channel mpi4py mpich mpi4py" that I found on the page you provided and it fixed my issue. THANKS!

Comment: you saved my day on this